# Why does the chip control the language to choose

Tags: c++, c, embedded, verilog

I've asked the question before what language should I learn for embedded development. Most embedded engineers said c and c++ are a must, but also pointed out that it depends on the chip.

Can someone clarify? Is it a compiler issue or what? Do chips come with their own specific compilers (like a c compiler or c++ compiler) and that's why you have to use the language the compiler knows? Is it not possible to code and compile it elsewhere, then burn it to the chip directly in its compiled state? (I think I heard an acquaintance say something to this effect)

I'm not sure how this works, as clearly I don't know much embedded systems or how they work. It's probably an easy answer for those of you who know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It "depends on the chip" in three possible ways:

1. Some very constrained architectures are not suited to C++, or at least C++ provides constructs not suited to such architectures so offers no benefit over C.  Most 8 bit devices fall into this category, but by no means all; I have seen useful C++ code implemented on MegaAVR for example.
2. Some devices are not supported by a C++ compiler.  For example Microchip's dsPIC/PIC24 compiler is C only (third-party tools may have C++ support).
3. The chip architecture is designed specifically for a particular language; for example INMOS Transputers invariably ran OCCAM.

As well as C, C++, other possibilities are assembler, Forth, Ada, Pascal and many others, but C is almost ubiquitous; few chip vendors will release a new architecture or device without a C compiler being available from day-one.  For other languages you will generally have to wait until a third-party decides to develop one, and that wait may be forever for a niche architecture.

> Is it not possible to code and compile it elsewhere, then burn it to the chip directly in its compiled state?

That is called cross-compilation or cross-development, and is the usual development method for embedded systems.  Most embedded systems lack the OS, filesystem, performance and memory resources to self-host a compiler, and most developers want the comfort of a sophisticated development environment with IDEs, debuggers etc. in a familiar user-oriented desktop OS.

> I'm not sure how this works, as
> clearly I don't know much embedded
> systems or how they work.

Get up-to-speed with some of these:

- http://www.state-machine.com/arm/Building_bare-metal_ARM_with_GNU.pdf
- http://www.eetimes.com/design/embedded
- [http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/020179523X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020179523X)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Systems-Firmware-Demystified-CD-ROM/dp/1578200997](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578200997)

Answer (score 7):

Probably, they meant some toolchains do not support C++.  Yes, many chips and boards do come with their own toolchains.  Different processors have different instruction sets, which means a different compiler (or more specifically a different backend).  That doesn't mean you always have to relearn everything.  Many of these are based on GCC (often considered the most ported compiler).  The final executable/image formats also vary, so you need a specific linker.  Most likely, you will be (cross-)compiling the chip on a "regular" computer, then burning it to the chip. However, that doesn't mean you can use a typical compiler and linker targeted towards a desktop operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many architectures for which a C compiler exists but a C++ compiler does not.  The smaller and less fully-featured a processor you choose, the more likely this situation is to occur.

For embedded development, you almost always compile the code 'elsewhere', as you say, and then send it to the chip for execution/debugging.  The process of compiling code for a different architecture than the compiler itself is built for is called 'cross-compiling'.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct: chips have variations on compilers. Most/many modern chips have a gcc port; but not all.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'embedded' is used to describe a vast range of hardware. Most embedded software engineering will consist of writing C/C++ code to produce a binary for a target microprocessor, but there are devices that you may work with that are not coded with compiled binary.

One example is a Programmable Logic Controller (PLC). These devices use a language called "[Ladder Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_logic)". It's a wonderful language. I have enjoyed working with it in the past.

Another thing you may encounter, as I have in the past, is devices that have interpreted BASIC emulators. Hopefully that is rare today.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ are a very good choice for firmware development. So the software you make will run on a embedded CPU/Microcontroller. In order to proper programmer the device, you will need to know the language and the device architecture.

The same code probably will not work in different devices. So, you have to learn the language, and the device architecture.

Another options are FPGAs, which are not microcontroller. FPGA are devices with specialized cell capable to transform itself in any type of synchronous circuit, including microcontroller. FPGAs are programed with Hardware Description languages, like verilog and VHDL. The "compiled" (synthesized) version of the software are called gateware.

The HDLs are the same languages used for ASICs designe also. The path to properly learn
the language are long. So I recommend start with C/C++ with pic form Microchip, which is a 
low cost and highly accepted microcontroller.

If you intend to do FPGA development, the knowledge gained with C/C++/pic will be helpfull and important, because must FPGAs have embedded CPU/Microcontroller inside.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct scientific reason for it.  In a lot of cases it has to do with the management and politics of the specific company.

Some companies are driven to create a turn key system and force you to buy that system and pay for maintenance.  It locks out the individual developers, but there are many companies and esp government agencies that prefer this model because the support is often much better and you can often drive the direction of their products to suit your needs.

Other companies do not have the staff or the talent and outsource the solution and sometimes take whatever they can get.  And you might end up with a one time developed tool that after the contractor leaves is never updated or fixed again, or if it is fixed it is a patch job by someone else.  It takes money to make money, but if you run out of money before you can sell your product you still fail.

Sometimes you have companies that both have a staff that maintains their in-house must buy from them tool AND has individuals that also contribute to open tools like gcc.

Sometimes the politics or management in the company have individuals that have a strong opinion of how the world must be and only allow tools to be developed for a specific language.  Or perhaps they are owned by or partner with or just like a company that has a specific language and this chip product came to be simply to support that language.

On top of all of this you have the very real technical problems of memory space, the quality and efficiency of the instruction set and how compiler friendly it is.  Some architectures may be fine for assembler, but higher level compiled code chews up the limited memory resources too quickly.

Gcc in particular has a lot of problems internally (not as a people but the software/source code itself).  I challenge you to write a back end, even with the tutorials that are out there.  A company requires specialised talent in order to create and then maintain a gcc backend year after year, otherwise you get dumped.  if your chip architecture is not 32 bit or bigger you are already fighting a losing battle with gcc, your chip architecture might be compiler friendly but just not friendly with the popular compilers design.

In the near future llvm is going to shine as a cross compiler relative to gcc because it has not yet built this internal bulk, and perhaps because the internal guts are themselves a defined language/system it may never suffer what has happened to gcc.  As more folks get comfortable with llvm we will see a number of architectures ported to it.  The msp430 backend was done specifically to demonstrate that you can add a target literally in an afternoon.  By the end of next month, some motivated individual could have all of the targets most of us have ever heard of ported to llvm.  And you dont have to build a cross compiler it is always a cross compiler.  I only mention llvm because the door is now open for targets that have suffered from bad tools to recover.

Some companies, microcontrollers in particular, can and will make the programming interface proprietary so that you must use their programming tool (and or hack it and take your chances with publishing those results and or a cat and mouse of them changing it to defeat you).  And they may have only made tools for Windows leaving the linux and apple folks hanging in the wind.  Or they make it so that the only binaries it will load are the ones generated by their tools, here again you may hack through the binary format allowing an alternate compiler, and they may or may not work to defeat you.

Despite the technical problems the biggest is the companies politics, management, marketing teams, and supply of or lack of talent in the engineering staff.  The bottom line, follow the dollars not the technology or science to understand why this language is supported and not that, or the support for this language is good, bad, or marginal.

What language to learn as a result of all of this?  Start with assembler on at least three different architectures.  Then C and then C++ if you feel you really need it.  C and assembler are your primary languages for embedded (depending on your definition of embedded).  No, we write assembler mostly for initial boot code and to support C, interrupt stuff or special instructions that are needed that the compiler cannot create.  There are places like microcontrollers where it may very well make sense to use assembler for various reasons like tools, limited chip resources, etc.  Even if you dont use assembler knowing it makes you a much better high level programmer.

You do need to decide what your definition of embedded is.  Is it api and library calls for an application on a(n embedded) linux system (indistinguishable from the same program/calls on a desktop system).  Or at the other end of the spectrum are you talking a microcontroller with maybe 256 or 1024 bytes (not mega or giga, but bytes) of program space?  Or something in the middle?  The majority of the "embedded" folks out there are closer to the api calls for applications on an operating system (rtos, linux, wince, etc), than the deeply embedded, so that means C, maybe C++ (always be able to fall back on C), trying to avoid python and other scripty languages that are resource hogs.

Answer (score 0):

Some 8-bit parts cannot efficiently access data from a stack.  Instead of using a stack to pass parameters, auto-variables and parameters are statically allocated; typically, a linker allocates the automatic variables for main() at one end of memory, and then allocate the variables for functions that are called by main and nothing else, then allocate the variables for functions that are called by those functions and nothing else, etc.  This will yield an optimal allocation fairly easily, subject to some caveats:

1. Recursion can only be supported by adding code to explicitly copy variables onto some sort of stack arrangement; in many compilers, it's simply not supported at all.

   If a function looks like it "might" call another function, the linker will assume it can do so in all cases (e.g. it may be that when 'foo' calls 'bar', one of its parameters might always have a value such that 'bar' won't call 'boz', but the linker won't know that).

   Any call to a function pointer with a certain signature will be regarded as a call to all functions with the same signature whose address is taken.

   If the evaluation of more than one parameter to a function requires making additional function calls, additional temporary storage must generally be pessimistically allocated even if optimal placement of the parameter storage could have avoided that.

There are many types of C programs for which the above restrictions pose no problem at all, and many more for which they pose a nuisance but not a huge one (e.g. by adding dummy parameters or return values to ensure different classes of indirectly-called functions have different signatures).  Unfortunately, the code generated by an C++ to C pre-compiler will almost always involve function pointers whose call graph cannot be reasonably divined, so using C++ on such a platform is apt to be difficult if not impossible.